# Get row by index from JTable

Tags: java, jtable

How to get row with index i froj JTable ? I looked at member functions but there is nothing like getRowAt . Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "row" object for a table, so nothing you could get with a getRow method.

You can ask `getValueAt()` to get the individual values, use it for each column and you have your complete row.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there is no such method. Write something like that:

```
public String[] getRowAt(int row) {
     String[] result = new String[colNumber];

     for (int i = 0; i < colNumber; i++) {
         result[i] = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
     }

     return result;
}
```

P.S - Use `table.getValueAt()` if you want to respect a rearranged by the user column order.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create a TableModel based on a list of POJOs.

It's then easy to add a method like:

```
   MyPojo getData(int index);
```

Have a look at this sample I wrote some time ago for a starting point:
http://puces-samples.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/puces-samples/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-sample/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/sample/ParticipantTableModel.java?revision=13&view=markup

Comment: In my opinion you should avoid the use of DefaultTableModel, as it is almost always unrelated to the structure of your pre-existing data that you are putting in the model. It was a mistake on Sun's part to add it to the sdk, imo.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
private void getIndexRow(){
    int i;
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    i=Integer.parseInt(myTable.getValueAt(row,column).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is using the table model's [`getDataVector()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getDataVector%28%29) method.

```
DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
Vector<Object> rowData = tm.getDataVector().elementAt(rowIndex);
```

Comment: possible but nothing you should want to do: wouldn't work anyway if the model isn't of type DefaultTableModel (you need a cast in your snippet). Passing around a part of the raw, uncopied underlying datastructure is asking for trouble as code might accidentally change its contents, thus violating the model's contract of notifying its listeners on change

Comment: Good point. It might be what someone wants to do though. I added a cast to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void jTable1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    int selectedRow;

    ListSelectionModel rowSM = jTable1.getSelectionModel();

      rowSM.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) 
        {
            ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();

            selectedRow = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();

            int numCols = jTable1.getColumnCount();

            model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

            System.out.print(" \n row " + selectedRow + ":");

            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(" " + model.getValueAt(selectedRow, j));
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Using this you can get value of whole row where u click on particular row.

Answer (score 0):

This function is working well for me.

```
private Object[] getRowAt(int row, DefaultTableModel model) {
    Object[] result = new Object[model.getColumnCount()];

     for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
         result[i] = model.getValueAt(row, i);
     }

     return result;
}
```