# java: JTable DefaultTableModel addRow(Object[] rowData)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm curious why DefaultTableModel has a

```
    public void addRow(Object[] rowData)
```

But no

```
    public Object[] getRow()
```

Is there a way to get an array of the row data without looping through the row cells one-by-one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get row by index from JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486130/get-row-by-index-from-jtable)

Comment: ok so getDataVector() is what i'm looking for?

Comment: You'd have to ask the designers, I assume they didn't feel the need for it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get an array of the row data without looping through the row cells one-by-one?

You need to create a custom TableModel to support this functionality.

Check out [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/)  and [List Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/list-table-model/) which does implement this type of functionality for you.

Well, actually it returns the row in a `List`, not an `Array`, but you can always use the `List.toArray(...)` method if you really need an Array.